# Component remount issue in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I am getting an issue in `this.setState` method while component remount. Flow is like whenever use login they will go user list page, and view user detail and data will be shown in popup. The flow is working fine. But whenever i go to another module say inquiry or dashboard module and get back to users module and and then clicking on view user detail, it is giving an error in this.setstate.

Notes: I am getting all the data in view method in user component but getting an error while doing setState in that method.

Here is an error :

> Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
>   application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
>   in the componentWillUnmount method.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Yash! It's very hard to help you with the information currently in your question. Try to include all relevant code and please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hello Yash, Can you please include your code snippets too?